# jQueryUI Dialog Box not working - Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I just can't figure this one out. The Dialog Box doesn't popup. I've tried all sorts of things but it just doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    // Dialog
    $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
            }
    });

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
    });
});  
</script>

<a href="#" id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</a>

<div id="dialog">This should popup</div>
</body>
```

What's wrong here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: [works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/PwVpU/)

Comment: Any errors in the console? What you have looks fine

Comment: Why does this need to be in a function? Set it in document ready like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/h7qNR/2/

Comment: do you get any script errors?

Comment: I think the `script` tag just after `body` missing `type="text/javascript"`. ie. `<body><script type="text/javascript">...`

Comment: script error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this it might be work.

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Where is `jquery.ui.dialog.js` in this scode?????

Please add this file into code as script tag....

you can put this JS file from here :

http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js

Comment: The link doesn't work. Isn't the code for Dialog included in the jQueryUI-File?

Answer (score 0):

`<script></script>` is not enough. Should be `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: i tried on jsfiddle and it worked. maybe something else is wrong with your code then? here: http://jsfiddle.net/xc4jy/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think the `script` tag just after `body` missing `type="text/javascript"`. ie. `<body><script type="text/javascript">...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the script block after the

```
<a href="#" id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</a>
<div id="dialog">This should popup</div>
```

block just before the body element and it should work.

You have to include also all the styling of the jQuery UI so that it looks nicer.

Comment: Is your jquery files accessible? Try to include this to the header `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. 
It is probably a compatibility issue, try including the below instead of what you have

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also to display the dialog properly, replace `jquery-ui-1.8.xx.custom.css` to match the `jquery-ui.min.js` version, I could not find a google ajax link.

I want to find an alternative solution but no idea if I can find one.